# Pop OS 22.04 can't update gir1.2-mutter-10, libmutter-10-0

Tags: apt, pop-os

For like two weeks now I see that gir1.2-mutter-10 and libmutter-10-0 have updates that are held back, but any attempt to install them fails. Even more, when simply trying to install them, I get error messages that are simply ridiculous. Apt claims that e.g. gir1.2-mutter-10 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.24) which isn't installable (but 3.24.33 is already installed). Those errors simply make no sense. Also, neither `apt full-upgrade`, nor `apt dist-upgrade` solve it, which normally install held back packages. Same with `apt install -f`. Sadly there's no support whatsoever on the Pop OS Reddit even after multiple users posting about that exact issue.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/58ndRZ34) is the output of trying to install gir1.2-mutter-10 from a few weeks back. It's not translated to english, but I'd say it still makes it clear enough what problems apt claims to have. Has anybody any idea how to solve this without reinstalling Pop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I never followed this one up with my solution. I ended up telling apt to do any changes it wants, even if they would break stuff. Then I kept uninstalling packages that threw errors until there wasn't any error left. It's been too long but it turned out there was some error in some apt list file, but I can't remember what exactly kept the update of some package (that wasn't ever mentioned before by apt) to not be found. One of the two packages mentioned in my OP depends on it indirectly, that's what caused the errors.

In the meantime I just got so sick and tired with Pop OS being more trouble than it was worth that I just kicked it from my system and installed Debian Testing. Far more stable and reliable. And since S76 rather works on yet another superfluous DE instead of giving it's users some basic stability first, it's even much more up to date while still being more stable and reliable. No more kernel updates breaking something.

Answer (score 18):

Try these commands

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't do anything.

Comment: What's the output of them?

Comment: The first has no output, the second only shows the same output that apt update would. Two packages are held back, nothing to update, install or remove.

Comment: This worked for me, installing the 42.3 version of gir1.2-mutter-10 over the 42.2 version.  Then I could do the rest of my upgrades.

Comment: I'm stuck on 42.1 with both packages.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: Works for me ....

Answer (score 6):

This is what fixed it for me.

```
# purge old apt configuration files
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo apt clean; sudo apt autoclean

# get fresh configuration files, resolve package conflicts
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install

# and finally resume the upgrade
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: Still no change, even when replacing upgrade with full-upgrade.

Comment: I think my problem was slightly different, as apt update was failing for me, complaining that it couldn't download a particular Pop index. That was causing a dependency conflict with an i386 package. Something slightly more dangerous would be to try to apt purge any partially installed packages, run apt update, and continue with the upgrade to help apt along.

Comment: Already considered just throwing both out and reinstalling them, but the same dependencies blocking their update also block their removal.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options here:

1. `sudo apt install gir1.2-mutter-10 libmutter-10-0 mutter mutter-common`
2. reboot and issue `apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: ..have you even read my comment? This would have failed in the first step, obviously, as it did all along.